# JStestDriver assertEquals ("000011",11) shouldn't be false?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, js-test-driver

I expected that JSTD treated "000011" (string) as not equal to 11 (number).

But, taking a look at he actual JSTD code, 
assertEquals returns

```
(a === e)
```

only if one of the elements are Objects, otherwise returns

```
(a == e)
```

isn't this wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's "wrong". They just have a different interpretation of what "equals" means. And since JavaScript provides `==` there must be a way to test this. If you want strict comparison, try `assertSame` (though I don't know if that is what you want, according to the documentation it seems to be the closest though).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/Assertions

Comment: "assertSame Fails if the expected and actual values are not references to the same object.", 
which is not what I want. 
I was expecting that assertSame did also a type check.

Comment: @Pierpaolo: Have  you tried using primitive values with `assertSame`?

Comment: @FelixKling: how do you mean? can you write an example?
Noah's answer surely helps.

But still, the question remains: why assertEquals has been implemented that way?

Comment: I mean have you tried `assertSame("11", 11)` and `assertSame(11, 11)`? But if *why assertEquals has been implemented that way* is your question, why don't you send an email to the developer?

Comment: assertSame works the way I expected assertEquals to work...
mmm... this dazzles me a bit...

Answer (score 2):

I can't really answer your main question (whether the assertion implementation is "wrong"), but to get at what you are trying to do, you can always write an assertion as such:

```
var str = '000011';
var num = 11;

assertTrue(str !== num);
```

Or if you want to ensure that the two variables have the same value and type:

```
assertTrue(str === num);
```

Comment: I guess this is the closest to my goal: to test whether a function that should return a string actually returns a string.